# Launching an application in windows from a webpage

Tags: php, javascript, wsh

I am working on a web based application at my work to make every once life easier. I am trying to build a page that would enable them launch the apps from with in the browser. I was thinking I could use Windows Script Host Run Method, but I have never used any windows based scripting languages. So to sum up my issue here, I need to click on a launch button with in the browser to launch text pad or other programs on Windows. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Update to question

Here is a possible answer,

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function runApp(){ 
   var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell"); 
   shell.run("notepad.exe", 1, True); 
  }
 </script>
```

```
<input type="button" name="button1" value="Run Notepad" onClick="runApp()" />
```

Comment: Is your workplace limited to Internet Explorer? If so, you should add it to the tags.

Comment: no, we can also use firefox or chrom. most of the staff tend to use firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for this to work legitimately is to have your users install a program prior to your website attempting to launch the program.  Your installation will register a URL Protocol .  When the Web Browser sees a non-http type protocol it will attempt to load the registered program that accepts the URL protocol your website is requesting.

[Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the responce. I looked at the script on msdn. Only problem is I haven't done any programming with VB or C++ since highschool which was almost 10 years ago. Would you be able to give me a sample example on how to integrate that in a php file. Thanks

Comment: No because as far as I know you cannot write windows applications in PHP.

Comment: looks like I am stuck. How about creating a .bat file that will be stored in the local computer? This might be wishful thinking but, would there be any method that will alow me to make php write the file with the user information, download the file, run it and delete it from the computer after task is completed. Thanks

Comment: A .bat file will not work for several reasons (mostly security related).

Answer (score 0):

you could do an href on your HTML page to a local or UNC path.

```
  <a href="file:///c:/path/executable.exe">click here</a>
```

Comment: Some browsers block `file:///` links. I believe Chrome and Firefox do by default.

Comment: hi, thanks for the responce. I tried your sudgestion in both ie and firefox too start notepad, it did not seem to open it.IE 8 and 9 might be blocking it as well. Also the function of the tool I am making will be to launch the applications and autologin by getting the login information for a MySql db. any ideas? thanks